# java if statements with math equation

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to make a code that applies tax rates to an input but I keep getting an error that says that I'm duplicating a local variable:

```
System.out.print("What percentage do you want to withhold for your medical savings account? ");
mw = pd.nextDouble();
taxtotal = gross - ud - mw;
Double taxtotal = pd.nextLine();
Double taxtotal = pd.next();
if (taxtotal > 2500) {
    taxtotal * 0.25;
}
```

Comment: It's because you have `taxtotal` twice.  Putting `Double` in front of it makes it a declaration, and you are only allowed to declare a variable once.  I think those should be different names, like `total` and `taxtotal`, not the same name, because you're using the same variable twice without actually using its value anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`taxtotal` variable declared 2 times. Variable can be declared one time and can be used as many times you want.

Variable declaration is, datatype and variable name ex:

```
Datatype variableName;
```

In the declaration itself we can do assignment also, like setting some value after equal sign.

```
Datatype variableName = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding Data type before the variable name is called Declaring a Variable. Eg - int sum, Double taxtotal, char ch etc.
2. You cannot use nextLine() method to store value in data types other than String. i.e.-

   ```
   double taxtotal = pd.nextLine(); //This is wrong
   ```

   The nextLine() method belongs to String data type. i.e.- You can use it only for String Variables otherwise it gives "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double" compiletime error.
   e.g.-

   ```
   String name = pd.nextLine();
   ```
3. You can declare variables only once. i.e. No need to Declare Data Type for Variable Each/Every time you use. i.e. Redeclaring the same variable you declared before gives you compiletime error!
   e.g -

   ```
   double taxtotal;            //Declaring Variable
   taxtotal = 0.00d;           //Initializing the variable
   taxtotal = pd.nextDouble();   //Reading and storing value in the variable
   ```
4. To dump the \n after nextLine() method used, you dont need to store it.  i.e. just call the next() method without storing into variable.

   ```
   taxtotal = pd.nextLine(); //nextLine() method called
   pd.next();          //calling next() function without storing in variable to dump \n
   ```
5. To save the mathematical operation you performed, you need to copy the output value to the respective variable otherwise the new value wont be saved.

   ```
   if (taxtotal > 2500) {
       taxtotal = taxtotal * 0.25; //updating and storing the multiplication value in taxtotal
   }
   ```